# What is buffer concept in C++?

Tags: c++14

```
cin.tie(NULL);
```

When we write it actually unties `cout` and `cin`. We have to flush `cout` manually or when buffer is full.

I cannot get buffer concept here.

Answer (score 8):

> ## What Does it Mean to Buffer in C++?
>
> Buffer is a generic term that refers to a block of memory that serves
>   as a temporary placeholder. You might encounter the term in your
>   computer, which uses RAM as a buffer, or in video streaming where a
>   section of the movie you are streaming downloads to your device to
>   stay ahead of your viewing. Computer programmers use buffers as well.
>
> ### Data Buffers in Programming
>
> In computer programming, data can be placed in a software buffer
>   before it is processed. Because writing data to a buffer is much
>   faster than a direct operation, using a buffer while programming in C
>   and C++ makes a lot of sense and speeds up the calculation process.
>   Buffers come in handy when a difference exists between the rate data
>   is received and the rate it is processed.
>
> ### Buffer vs. Cache
>
> A buffer is temporary storage of data that is on its way to other
>   media or storage of data that can be modified non-sequentially before
>   it is read sequentially. It attempts to reduce the difference between
>   input speed and output speed. A cache also acts as a buffer, but it
>   stores data that is expected to be read several times to reduce the
>   need to access slower storage.
>
> ### How to Create a Buffer in C++
>
> Usually, when you open a file a buffer is created. When you close the
>   file, the buffer is flushed. When working in C++, you can create a
>   buffer by allocating memory in this manner:
>
> ```
> char* buffer = new char[length];
> ```
>
> When you want to free up the memory allocated to a buffer, you do so
>   like this:
>
> ```
> delete[ ] buffer;
> ```
>
> Note: If your system is low on memory, the benefits of buffering
>   suffer. At this point, you have to find a balance between the size of
>   a buffer and the available memory of your computer.

Source: https://www.thoughtco.com/definition-of-buffer-p2-958030

Comment: Maybe the downvote is because it's a copy of someone else's text. Sure, you do give them credit, but it's still just a copy/paste of someone else's text.

Comment: @NicolBolas That's true. So, if I would have written my own answer with the same thoughts, would it have been a better answer?

Comment: If the question is answered by copying and pasting from a web site, and also the question is asking to explain a high-level concept, these are signs that the question is *not appropriate for Stack Overflow* and therefore *should not have been answered*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Mind telling me why are you downvoting my answer?

Comment: @cYee I think his main point is that the question should have not been answered. I do not agree with that though, so I have read your answer and since it seems to be correct, I have upvoted it.

Comment: It was just that I wish to know, is that I have answer it wrongly, if that is the case, It will be helpful for me to improve my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To know about `Write Buffer`, we have to know why it exists in the first place.

**Why write buffering?**

Writing a file to disk is an `high I/O traffic process`. It is expensive to a slow disk.

For a simple file system to write, it involves `multiple I/Os` (Read/write index node, read/write data bitmap, write disk block ...)

It is possible to write without buffer, if filesystem writing can be more efficient and as fast as writing to the ram, we might not need a write buffer.

In order to overcome the `high cost of I/Os`, writing it to a buffer can `reduce I/O traffic`:

- to delay writes, so filesystem can batch updates,
- to avoid some I/Os, such as file creation and deletion at the same time since most fs buffer keep buffer in memory between some interval, so anything create and delete between the interval can be avoided.

It also means you can either manually flush your buffer by calling `fsync` or let the file system batch update it for you, but there is one drawback, If your system go down at that interval, your data is lost.